# Подсчет количества повторных элементов в массиве

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Есть массив arr, размером n (не менее 20 элементов). Данные массива заполнены рандомно. Числа от 0 до 9. Подсчитать количество повторений для каждого из элементов массива. Сколько будет 0, 1, 2 и т.д. Вывести результат в консоль.

Создаю массив:

```
int [] arr = new int []{9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 7, 8, 4, 3, 9, 2, 1, 7, 4, 6, 4, 1, 2}
```

Выполняю цикл, инкрементируя значение переменной i, с типом данных int (0 до длины массива).
Дальше нужно сделать так, чтобы срабатывал счетчик повторяющихся элементов.

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[] { 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 7, 8, 4, 3, 9, 2, 1, 7, 4, 6, 4, 1, 2};
        int[] counter = new int[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            counter[arr[i]]++;
        }

        System.out.println("value\tcount");
        for (int i = 0; i < counter.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + "\t" + counter[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Неправильно выводит данные, в count выводятся только первые 10 символов данного массива в том же порядке, что записаны в arr

Comment: Исправил: во втором цикле вместо массива arr нужно counter

Comment: Спасибо огромное, работает)

Comment: Можешь объснить синтаксис написания counter[arr[i]]++; ? Буду очень признателен

Comment: var index = arr[i];
var cnt = counter[index];
cnt++;
counter[index] = cnt;

Answer (score 2):

Создаешь 2 массив arr2 на 10 элементов, в котором находятся цифры от 0 до 9. И при прохождения цикла в 1-ом массиве, берешь **значение** элемента, и инкрементишь значения arr2[**значение**].